# Dialog Flow Intent Static Responses Repeat before Going Through All 7

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am testing static text responses in a dialogflow intent where there are 7 unique responses and every-time i test on: simulator, google_home or cellphone_google_assistant it can't get through all 7 without repeating ones it has already said.

I would expect it to and this paste from their docs certainly imply it should:

> Static text response
>
> In the Responses section of your intent, you can define one or more
>   static text responses that will be returned when a user's input
>   matches that particular intent. If you have more than one text
>   response defined, your agent will select responses to return at random
>   (but never use a variation twice in a row) until all responses have
>   been used. We recommend adding several varieties of text responses to
>   make your agent more conversational.

does anyone have any thoughts/input/guidance on this or have experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line "select responses to return at random" is the operative phrase here. It will pick one at random, but not pick that same one twice in a row. It does not go through them as a list in order. This is meant to be similar to how humans can vary replies so they don't sound... robotic.

The static responses should all be equivalent answers. If you do want to have "escalating" answers (ie - the first time they ask for help they get a short help, as they keep asking for more help, they get longer and more detailed answers) you'll need to implement that as a fulfillment webhook and keep count how many times they have triggered the Intent. Libraries such as [multivocal](https://multivocal.info/) provide tools to assist with this.